# Java Generics: Type cast issue (ClassCastException)

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly cast a generic object in java to a type that extends the generic object.

For example, say I some setup like the following:

```
public class Parameters extends SomeCustomMap<String, String>
{
   ...
}

public class SomeCustomMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V>
{
    public SomeCustomMap<K, V> getSubSet(...)
    {
        SomeCustomMap<K, V> subset;

        ...

        return subset;
    }
}

class ExampleApp
{
    private void someMethod()
    {
        Parameters params;
        Parameters paramsSubSet;

        try
        {
            ...

            paramsSubSet = (Parameters) params.getSubSet(...);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Running code similar to the above consistently throws a ClassCastException, the likes of which I do not fully understand. Any assitence for how to correctly set up a scenario similar to the above would be appreciated! Namely, how might I properly cast the the SomeCustomMap object that is returned from the params.getSubSet(...) method back to a Parameters object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show more code for `getSubSet` (in particular, parts that construct the object that will be returned by `return subset;`), and also any overrides in the `Parameters` class that change the object that will be returned by `getSubSet`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public <T extends SomeCustomMap<K, V>> T getSubSet(...){
    T subset = (T)this.clone();
    subset.clear();

    return subset;
}
```

creation looks a little funny - feel free to change it to whatever you want :)

As a bonus you will not need to cast :)

```
paramsSubSet = params.getSubSet(...)
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually tried something very similar to this, but was only casting to T on return, rather than creating a new `instance` of T (as the other commenters have pointed out)... It all makes sense now. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Your Problem is that the Subset returned by getSubSet is a of instance SomeCustomMap and not of Parameters.

This problem does not deal with generics. You will get the same problem if you did not use generics.

I don't know how you create an instance of subset but maybe you could use the template desing pattern and some generics to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Though I've commented asking for more information, based on what you've posted so far, I think `getSubSet` is constructing a  `SomeCustomMap` to return (with `new SomeCustomMap`) somewhere. If you don't override `getSubSet` in `Parameters`, then `Parameters.getSubset` will return a `SomeCustomMap` (the base class), not a `Parameters`, so your typecast to `Parameters` fails.

(Hot tip, if you override `getSubSet` in the `Parameters` class, you can change the return type to `Parameters` and avoid the typecast.)

Comment: Yes, you are correct in that I am doing a `someSubset = new SomeCustomMap<K, V>()` and filling this subset with the data from the parent (`this`). And for now, say I do not have any overrides in the Parameters class; Is there any way this can be done without the  override?

Comment: I don't know what the best way is. I see you accepted an answer that uses `clone()` already, but you could also use methods on `this.getClass()`, or you could factor out a (small) protected function whose only purpose is to construct an object of the right type, and override that.

Answer (score 1):

Generics don't inherently have anything to do with casting (save that due to the nature of erasure, generic parameters cannot be checked during a cast).

If you're getting a `ClassCastException` in this case, it means that the object returned really is not an instance of `Parameters`.  Just before you cast, try calling

```
System.out.println(params.getSubSet(...).getClass());
```

and see what the actual run-time class of the subset is.  Chances are the problem lies elsewhere, as your expectation that the subset is a Parameters object is almost certainly not correct at runtime - it's a `SomeCustomMap` or some *other* subclass thereof.

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained, the issue is that the actual object you are constructing in `getSubSet()` is not an instance of `Parameters`.

Here's one possible workaround.  I don't love it, but it is a way to declare the method in `SomeCustomMap` but have its return value be typed correctly for any subclass.

```
public static <T extends SomeCustomMap<K, V>> getSubSet(T fullSet)
{
    T subset;

    ... (use fullSet instead of this)

    return subset;
}
```